Downloading files from a list of urls
I need to download files from a list of URLs. The size of the list URLs is between 3000 and 6000. These files are small in size with the largest being 25KB. I have a function that can download a file but when used for multiple files as in this case, it puts pressure on the heap as object instances are created on the fly for each URL to be downloaded. The function is below:
fun download(
    dest: File,
    url: String,
    filename: String,
    onPreExecute: () -> Unit = {},
    onPostExecute: (Any) -> Unit = {},
    onProgress: (DownloadState) -> Unit = {},
): Job {
    return appScope.executeAsyncTask(
        onPreExecute = onPreExecute,
        onPostExecute = onPostExecute,
        onProgress = onProgress,
        doInBackground = { reportProgress: suspend (progress: DownloadState) -> Unit ->
            try {
                val httpUrl = URL(url)
                val connection = httpUrl.openConnection()
                connection.connect()
                val totalBytes = connection.contentLengthLong
                httpUrl.openStream().use { ins ->
                    BufferedInputStream(ins).use { bis ->
                        FileOutputStream(File(dest, filename)).use { fos ->
                            var bytesRead: Int
                            var totalBytesRead = 0L
                            val buffer = ByteArray(4096)
                            // Downloading started
                            val ds = DownloadState(
                                downloading = true,
                                fileSizeBytes = totalBytes
                            )
                            while (
                                bis.read(
                                    /* b = */ buffer,
                                    /* off = */0,
                                    /* len = */buffer.size
                                ).also { bytesRead = it } != -1
                            ) {
                                totalBytesRead += bytesRead
                                // Report download progress
                                reportProgress(
                                    ds.copy(
                                        bytesDownloaded = totalBytesRead,
                                        progress = (totalBytesRead / totalBytes.toFloat())
                                    )
                                )
                                fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                            }
                            // Downloading finished
                            reportProgress(ds.copy(downloading = false))
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                Log.e(TAG, e.message.toString())
                reportProgress(DownloadState(error = e, downloading = false))
                throw e
            }
        }
    )
}

I call that function in a view model as follows:
private fun download(directory: File) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            val audios = listOf(/* Audio(...) */)

            if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {
                audios.forEachIndexed { i, s ->
                    val count = i + 1
                    val id = s.id
                    val done = count == audios.size

                    val filename = audio.getFilename(id)
                    val dest = File(directory, audio.getDirectory())

                    if (!dest.exists()) dest.mkdirs()

                    // If file already exists skip it
                    if (File(dest, filename).exists()) {
                        _uiState.update {
                            val audioCount = it.audioCount + 1
                            it.copy(
                                audioCount = audioCount,
                                syncCompleted = done,
                                audioDownloadDone = done,
                            )
                        }
                        return@forEach
                    }

                    downloadClient.download(
                        dest = dest,
                        filename = filename,
                        url = audio.url,
                        onPostExecute = {
                            _uiState.update {
                                val audioCount = it.audioCount + 1
                                it.copy(
                                    audioCount = audioCount,
                                    syncCompleted = done,
                                    audioDownloadDone = done,
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            _uiState.update {
                it.copy(
                    syncCompleted = true,
                    audioDownloadErred = true,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

After a few downloads has completed, the GC logs a message like waiting for allocated... then the system kills the app with a signal 9.
How do I go about fixing this issue, so the download completes without the app getting killed?
Please keep in mind, I also need to update the UI with the download progress.
Feel free to suggest other options/libraries with code that would help get around this issue.

I would start by using OkHttp and Okio rather than the ancient HttpUrlConnection. I would also use a work queue rather than launching thousands of coroutines.

I came up with a fix for the issue. Instead of using HttpUrlConnection I switched to Ktor then created an instance that wrapped the list of URLs. My downloader implementation looks as follows:
suspend fun downloadFiles(
    directory: File,
    files: List<AudioFile>,
    onComplete: () -> Unit,
    onPostExecute: () -> Unit
) {
    HttpClient(Android).use { client ->
        files.forEach { df ->
            val dest = File(directory, df.savePath)
            val file = File(dest, df.filename)

            if (!dest.exists()) dest.mkdirs()
            if (file.exists()) {
                onComplete()
                return@forEach
            }

            client.prepareGet(df.url).execute { response: HttpResponse ->
                val channel: ByteReadChannel = response.body()

                while (!channel.isClosedForRead) {
                    val packet = channel.readRemaining(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE.toLong())
                    while (!packet.isEmpty) {
                        val bytes = packet.readBytes()
                        file.appendBytes(bytes)
                    }
                }
                onComplete()
            }
        }
        onPostExecute()
    }
}

With the above code, I reused the HttpClient for all the files to be downloaded then closing it at the end.
